# CIDR < 5 not allowed

Tags: windows, networking, ip, lan, network-adapter

**Problem**

Two NICs have been connected using an ethernet cable. The ethernet adapters have been configured as follows:

NIC I

```
IP: 8.0.0.1
Subnet mask: 248.0.0.0
```

NIC II

```
IP: 8.0.0.2
Subnet mask: 248.0.0.0
```

If a subnet mask of 0.0.0.0, 128.0.0.0, 192.0.0.0, 224.0.0.0 or 240.0.0.0 would like to be configured the following message occurs:

`The combination of IP address and subnet mask is invalid. All of the bits in the network address portion of the IP address are set to 0. Please enter a valid combination of IP address and subnet mask.`

According to this IP calculator a CIDR of 0 is invalid, while X>=1 is allowed.

**Question**

Why is CIDR < 5 not allowed? Does this mean the lowest possible CIDR is 5 and thus 248.0.0.0?

Comment: I don't understand, why this should be a problem. Do you have the need to have several millions of networked devices in just one network? No. You only have two. What's the problem in using 255.255.255.0 or some such?

Comment: I agree, but I do not understand why CIDR < 5 is not allowed.

Comment: Well, nobody owns such a large IPv4 network and it's more than the greatest that's reserved for private use (10.0.0.0/8).

Comment: What command are you running that produces that error message? Please clarify the question and tag it with the specific system you're using.

Comment: The OS is Windows 7 and 8. Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center > Ethernet > Properties > IPv4. The message appears if an IP lower than 8.0.0.1 or CIDR < 5 would like to be configured.

Comment: Do you understand, why you need a CIDR of at least 6, if you want to configure the IP address 7.0.0.1, while for 3.0.0.1 it would be even 7?

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. CIDR = 6: 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 = 7, CIDR = 7: 2^1 + 2^0 = 3, CIDR = 8: 2^0 = 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is easy. Your IP address of

```
8.0.0.1
```

has this bit representation:

```
0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

With a bitmask lower than 5 the network address would be 0. 
This is not allowed, i.e. for 8.0.0.1/4 we would have

```
0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
net ^host in network
```